# How to do a Rails webapp for writing an ebook collaboratively?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write an ebook and I would like to create (if there's none already) a Web Application that could meet most (if not all) of my requirements:

- An online web application in Rails (because it is what I know)
- Editing in a wiki style syntax
- Registred users can leave comments on each paragraph of the book but can't change the content
- Registred users are notified when a new chapter is available online
- Content can be used to generate a book (or an intermediate format like DocBook)

I wish to publish my book on paper once it is written (using Lulu.com and the like).  So, the application should be able to output the content of the website in PDF ordered like a real book (title page, TOC, Introduction, etc.)  Also, I want to be able to record the comments from the (beta) readers while I'm writing it (like [PragProg does](http://pragprog.com/frequently-asked-questions/beta-books)).

Do you know if there is some existing plugins that could give me a head start or an existing Rails application that I could customize to meet my needs?

Comment: Take a look at these general resources: http://authoringebooks.com/ http://www.larubyconf.com/presentations/5 (at LA Ruby Conf Michael Hartl described a tool he has created but not published to create ebooks)

Comment: Wouldn't any application work?  Is there a reason why it has to be a rails application?  Also this doesn't seem to be programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the perfect solution but it is close enough (the only thing missing is the online collaboration feature).  I found a Ruby framework called [Kitabu](http://fnando.github.com/public/kitabu.html) that I can use.

> FEATURES:
>
> - Write PDF using Markdown or Textile
> - text markup Book layout support
> - Syntax highlight theme based on Textmate
> - Generate a PDF with a single rake task
> - Table of Contents automatically generated from chapter titles

Another similar Ruby application that I found is [git-scribe](https://github.com/schacon/git-scribe).